# Android EditText in AlertDialog seems too wide

Tags: android, android-edittext, width, android-alertdialog

It seems like the EditText in the image below is too wide.  I assume that I have misused the SDK in some way and until convinced otherwise I am not looking for a way to specify some number of margin/padding pixels on the sides of the `EditText`.

[image]

This one looks more appropriate.

[image]

Here's my code (that creates the first, 'Create Tag', dialog):

```
final Dao<Tag, Integer> tagDao = getHelper().getTagDao();

final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setSingleLine(true);
input.setHint(R.string.create_tag_dialog_hint);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(input);
builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.create_tag_dialog_title));
builder.setPositiveButton(
    getString(R.string.create_tag_dialog_positive),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Tag tag = new Tag(value);
            try {
                    tagDao.create(tag);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
builder.setNegativeButton(
    getString(R.string.create_tag_dialog_negative), null);
builder.show();
```

Sorry for the length of the post and thanks for any helpful comments.

Answer (score 30):

Just sorted this myself. Using an instance of `AlertDialog`, you can specify `setView` and pass in spacing parameters. This will work.

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
alertDialog.setView(input, 10, 0, 10, 0); // 10 spacing, left and right
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Clicked
    }
});
alertDialog.show();
```

Edit: I'm aware this question is old, but no solution was provided.

Comment: Heads Up: `alertDialog.setView(View, int, int, int, int);` does not exist in the new android api versions.

Comment: @DavidPassmore do you have any potential substitutes for this method??

Comment: @DavidPassmore no, it exists. At least if you are using the appcompat v7 AlertDialog

Comment: Builder.setView can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.appcompat) 
Inspection info:This API has been flagged with a restriction that has not been met.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setSingleLine(true);
layout.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
input.setHint("Hint");
layout.addView(input);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
```

Moreover, `setSingleLine` is deprecated. You should use `InputStyle`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the deprecation of SingleLine.  They don't mention it everywhere in the documentation.  Still, it doesn't seem like I should have to pick some number of pixels to correct this.  I am assuming that the present result is incorrect because of my misuse of `AlertDialog.Builder` (or perhaps it is entirely the wrong technique).

Answer (score 1):

Set the layout marginleft and layout marginright to 5sp.  The margin sets the space around the view group.  Take a look at [ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to apply that...  but despite sp not being px, it would still be me arbitrarily setting some spacing rather than letting android use a default spacing.  I don't want to adjust the layout to my personal preference, I want Android to do it to it's preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some padding on your `EditText` using the [setPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method.   This should add a gap between the edge of the EditText and the border of the dialog.  N

Comment: Padding applies to things inside of the view so `EditText.setPadding()` creates space around the text inside of the `EditText`.  I did try `((View) input.getParent()).setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10)` after `builder.setView(input)`, but this resulted in a null pointer exception.  Regardless, I don't want to find a way to customize it to my personal preference of 5px or such, I want to allow the SDK to format it correctly.  I assume I am using the SDK incorrectly and thus the formatting doesn't look right.