# Resizing EditText inside of an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking for a way to resize (so it doesn't touch the edges) an `EditText` inside of an `AlertDialog`.

[image]

*My sample code*

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity.this);

alert.setTitle("Test");

EditText textBox = new EditText(myActivity.this);
alert.setView(textBox);

alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // do nothing 
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
// do nothing
}
});

alert.show();
```

I've tried solutions provided here with no success:

- [An Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224927/how-to-set-edittext-box-height-and-width-programmatically-in-android)
- [Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927208/android-edittext-in-alertdialog-seems-too-wide)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add your `EditText` inside a `LinearLayout` and set margins to that layout.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Test");

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(20, 0, 30, 0);

EditText textBox = new EditText(myActivity.this);
layout.addView(textBox, params);

alert.setView(layout);

alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // do nothing 
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
// do nothing
}
});

alert.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, this helped to put the right pieces in the right places.

Comment: For me, this made the editText look better -> params.setMargins(55, 0, 55, 0);