# Limit the width of an EditText within an AlertDialog with Layout Params?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

**The Question:**

- *How can we limit the width of an EditText contained within an AlertDialog via LayoutParams?*

**The Assumptions**:

- I have an AlertDialog, whose width is set to be rather large;
- Within this dialog lives an EditText, whose width should be ~1/3 of its container;

**The Minor Details**:

- The EditText has the following types:

  - TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
  - TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
  - TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
- The height/width of the AlertDialog is set in pixels, scaled via density (see the code);

**The Confusion:**

- Given the following code, why does the EditText end up spanning the entire width of the AlertDialog?

**The Code**:

- Note that the EditText is set to {100,100} via LayoutParams, while the AlertDialog is set to {900,500}

```java
    private void show_activation_prompt()
      {    

        // =============================================================
        // ======== create EditText which filters text =================
        // =============================================================

        // filter for alphanumerics, insert dashes during entry, capitalize, and turn off suggestions
        final TextWatcher  textEditorWatcher = new SafeTextWatcher(); //custom
        final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(100,100);
        final EditText edittext= new EditTextPersist(mContext);

        edittext.addTextChangedListener(textEditorWatcher);
        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT               | 
                              InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS |
                              InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
                              );
        edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        //edittext.setEms(10); //doesn't work either


        // =============================================================
        // ======== create alert dlg, set btn callbacks ================
        // =============================================================

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Upgrade", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
          {
            String activationKey = edittext.getText().toString();
            on_key_entered(activationKey);
          }
        } );
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
          {
            post_activation_result(QlmLicense.ACTIVATION_INVALID);
          }
        } );


        // =============================================================
        // ======== configure the AlertDialog/EditText =================
        // =============================================================

        int nWidth, nHeight;
        final float scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        nWidth  = (int) (900 * scale + 0.5f);
        nHeight = (int) (500 * scale + 0.5f);

        builder.setView(edittext)
               .setMessage("Enter an Activation Key:")
               .setTitle("Upgrade From Trial Version")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .show()
               .getWindow()
               .setLayout(nWidth,nHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Try set your `edittext` into an `LinearLayout` and set `margin` for this `layout` before add view of `dialog` for `layout`. Hope this answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345735/resizing-edittext-inside-of-an-alertdialog/9345820#9345820

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you much. This answers the question of "How to accomplish" limiting the width within AlertDialog. A more useful & direct question is "Why don't LayoutParams work when applied to an EditText within an AlertDialog". I will make the edit! Thank you for providing the means :)

Comment: Given the more specific question, if you find a means of combining the solution you found with the use of LayoutParams, I will gladly accept your answer as correct if you post one!

Comment: Nice if it could help you. I am not at home right now, so I will post the answer when I return home ^^. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had simple answer for your question to apply `LayoutParams` for `Edittext` in `AlertDialog` by change `LayoutParams` into `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` and call `edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);` after calling `dialog.show()`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

int nWidth, nHeight;
final float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
nWidth  = (int) (900 * scale + 0.5f);
nHeight = (int) (500 * scale + 0.5f);

final FrameLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
final EditText edittext= new EditText(this);

            //edittext.addTextChangedListener(textEditorWatcher);
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS |
                            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
);

            // =============================================================
            // ======== create alert dlg, set btn callbacks ================
            // =============================================================

builder.setPositiveButton("Upgrade", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
     {
           String activationKey = edittext.getText().toString();
                    //on_key_entered(activationKey);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), activationKey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
} );
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //post_activation_result(QlmLicense.ACTIVATION_INVALID);
    }
});


builder.setView(edittext)
.setMessage("Enter an Activation Key:")
                        .setTitle("Upgrade From Trial Version")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .show()
                        .getWindow()
                        .setLayout(nWidth, nHeight);


//Change setLayoutParams to here       
edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```