# Can't change EditText margins programmatically inside AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog in my app that contains an EditText field. This dialog needs to be generated programmatically and should match the way the  EditTextPreference dialog looks that is displayed automatically by Android when a user edits text by touching an EditTextPreference. This all works, but the size of the EditText inserted programmatically is too wide and doesn't match the one displayed by the EditTextPreference when touched. The following two images show the problem.

**EditText looks like this when added to the AlertDialog using setView():**

[image: EditText looks like this when added to the AlertDialog using setView()]

**But should look like this:**

[image: Should look like this]

Here is the XML code in the XML responsible for the EditTextPreference:

```
<EditTextPreference
            android:title="Enter Name"
            android:key="name"
            android:defaultValue=""
            android:summary=""
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:lines="2"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />
```

And the Java code responsible for my dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Date");

final EditText input = new EditText(mainActivity);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
input.setLayoutParams(lp);
input.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.TOP|android.view.Gravity.LEFT);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
input.setLines(1);
input.setMaxLines(1);
input.setText(lastDateValue);
alertDialog.setView(input);
```

Comment: Show xml file and code related to AlertDialog

Comment: Please edit the question and provide us with code and xml layout file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9345820/2826147

Comment: @AmitVaghela Thanks, I tried that and it works. However, I am worried that the hard-coded margin values won't match future theme changes in the Android UI. Is there a way I can retrieve the default margin values for the current theme?

Answer (score 28):

You have to add a container before doing that, e.g `LinearLayout`

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Date");

LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
final EditText input = new EditText(mainActivity);
input.setLayoutParams(lp);
input.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.TOP|android.view.Gravity.LEFT);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
input.setLines(1);
input.setMaxLines(1);
input.setText(lastDateValue);
container.addView(input, lp);

alertDialog.setView(container);
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks!. It's helped

Comment: @Madhu if it did help, could you accept as the right answer?

Comment: One who posted the question can accept the answer. i don't have that privilege

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were the one asking

Comment: @Shayan Samad can you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Date");

final EditText input = new EditText(mainActivity);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
input.setLayoutParams(lp);
input.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.TOP|android.view.Gravity.LEFT);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
input.setLines(1);
input.setMaxLines(1);
input.setText(lastDateValue);
alertDialog.setView(input);
```

Please change your code as above and provide desire all margins

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already. Adding LayoutParams directly to the EditText doesn't seem to make a difference. Perhaps wrapping the EditText in a LinearLayout first would work, per Amit Vaghela's comment.

Comment: Then you have to inflate custome layout for AlertDialog

Comment: Any luck with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without extra container layout, only add this to your `alertDialog` :

```
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
    p.setMargins(50, 20, 50, 20); // You can change the margins for your need
    editText.requestLayout();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Android XML with the needed and formatted Elements. Inflate the XML/view and add view to dialog button.

This way the UI design and the code is cleaner separated. The Android XML Editor with preview makes it easier to get the wanted optical results.

The Example uses **Databinding** and so the XML/View is addressed via Databinding `DialogEditTextBinding.inflate([...])` and the result is accessed via databinding `dialogBinding.editText.getText().toString()`.

#### Java Code in Fragment/Activity

```
final DialogEditTextBinding dialogBinding = DialogEditTextBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Date");

alertDialog.setView(dialogBinding);

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
    (dialog, whichButton) -> {
        String editText = dialogBinding.editText.getText().toString();
        doSomething(editText);
    });
```

#### Android XML for Dialog extra Elements

`dialog_edit_text.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

#### PS

PS: The example is combined out of my code and your code, so it may contain errors.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @LeonardoSibela answer, I made this simple function in kotlin to show a dialog with an edittext and a callback.

```kotlin
    private fun showEditDialog(title: String, preFill: String, onSubmit: (text: String) -> Unit) {
        val editText = EditText(requireContext()).apply {
            setText(preFill)
        }
        val viewContainer = LinearLayout(requireContext()).apply {
            orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
            val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            ).apply {
                setMargins(16.dp, 0, 16.dp, 0)
            }
            addView(editText, lp)
        }
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
            .setView(viewContainer)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ -> onSubmit(editText.text.toString()) }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ -> }
            .show()
    }
```

And you could use it like this:

```
showEditDialog("Change name", "") { name ->
   viewModel.updateName(name)
}
```